# Door knob installation direction

Tags: doors, doorknob

I bought this new set of door knob and strangely the screws are positioned vertically like below photo.

[image]

Also the lock in vertical is unlock. Is that right?

**UPDATE 1**

It is this model that I bought

Kwikset Signature Hancock Polished Brass Keyed Entry Door Knob

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kwikset-Signature-Hancock-Polished-Brass-Keyed-Entry-Door-Knob/1000208209

Comment: Does the latch and lock function as it should? If so, I think you can assume it is in correctly. Normally these will only go together one way.

Comment: FYI, there may be an alternative bolt faceplate in your kit that would fit the square-cornered mortise better. You pop the rounded one off and replace it.

Answer (score 3):

What you ask, all depends on who made the latchset. Some make it where the screws are horizontal, others make it so they are vertical as you have.

I think Schlage and Kwikset are an example of this.

The same may be true for the lock. In some cases on some locksets, the part where the tang of the lock has two options to place it, on horizontal lock, the other, vertical lock. This may or may not be your case. This is more often seen with deadbolts with thumb turns.

Comment: The knob assembly screw location is just as Jack describes, most of the ones I have installed are top to bottom but there are some that are on the sides, I believe these are rare because the screw at the edge of the door side has to go through the mechanism making it weaker.+

Comment: In 30 years of building and remodeling houses, I've NEVER seen a lockset with vertical screws. EVERY lockset I've ever serviced or installed has had a horizontal orientation...

Comment: I updated with the exact model from Kwikset. The thing is I cannot turn the screw horizontally as there is no way to put it in horizontally. There is no hole

Comment: @BillWeckel, I was going to make mention about how the knobs nowadays are cast so they can only go in one way. Seems the OP confirmed.... I am certain I set one, perhaps a houseful recently, but long enough ago to not be certain...